# Issue with removing duplicates in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Edit: This has been solved thanks to fsl, duplicated where removed and the issue was the index that needed to be reseted.

I have this dataframe:

```
  Ubicacion       lat       lon
0         a  19.28034 -99.17121
1         b  19.28333 -99.17535
2         c  19.28028 -99.16887
3         a  19.28034 -99.17121
4         b  19.28333 -99.17535
5         c  19.28028 -99.16887
6         b  19.28333 -99.17535
7         d  19.29259 -99.17757
8         d  19.29259 -99.17757
9         d  19.29259 -99.17757
```

And I want to remove all duplicate rows, so I use:

```
ubicaciones_finales = ubicaciones_finales.drop_duplicates(keep="first")
```

And I get this:

```
  Ubicacion       lat       lon
0         a  19.28034 -99.17121
1         b  19.28333 -99.17535
2         c  19.28028 -99.16887
7         d  19.29259 -99.17757
```

Everything seems fine except that rows go 0, 1, 2 and then 7. So when I run:

```
 for k, row in ubicaciones_finales.iterrows():
    print(k)

I get:
0
1
2
7
```

How do I solve this? btw, already check [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

```
df.drop_duplicates()
    brand style  rating
0  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
2  Indomie   cup     3.5
3  Indomie  pack    15.0
4  Indomie  pack     5.0
```

And its the same, it goes from 0 to 2 witouth 1. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, go with `reset_index` or simply pass `ignore_index=True`:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(keep='first').reset_index(drop=True)

# or 

df = df.drop_duplicates(keep='first', ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
  Ubicacion       lat       lon
0         a  19.28034 -99.17121
1         b  19.28333 -99.17535
2         c  19.28028 -99.16887
3         d  19.29259 -99.17757
```

Comment: Thank you, didn´t understand what ignore_index was about til know